# Finding a natural homomorphism between two relative cohomology groups

Tags: homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles

I'm trying to better understand how relative homology/cohomology works in order to make use of them for a specific example in mind. Here I'll be working with cohomology over the integers.

Let $A \subset B$ be two topological spaces, $E$ be a fiber bundle over $B$ with projection map $\pi$, and $E|_A$ be the fiber bundle over $A$ obtained from restricting $E$ over the new base space $A$.

I'm interested in both $H^k (B,A)$ and $H^k (E, E|_A)$, and, in particular, whether there is a natural homomorphism from $H^k (B,A)$ to $H^k (E, E|_A)$, possibly induced by $\pi$. So my question is:

> Does $\pi$ induce a homomorphism from $H^k (B,A)$ to $H^k (E, E|_A)$? If so, how does one go about finding it, or how is it defined? Does one need stronger conditions on the topological spaces or the fiber bundle to get a meaningful answer?

In general I don't fully understand how relative homology/cohomology works so I don't know where to start in answering this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At least in the case that $E$ is a vector bundle, the answer is yes, because then $\pi$ is in fact a homotopy equivalence of pairs. The same should still hold true for fiber bundles with contractible fibers under some mild additional niceness conditions.

Comment: Every continuous map $f : (X, A) \to (Y, B)$ (i.e. a continuous map $f : X \to Y$ such that $f(A) \subseteq B$) induces maps $f_* : H_k(X, A) \to H_k(Y, B)$ and $f^* : H^k(Y, B) \to H^k(X, A)$. These maps are constructed in much the same way as the non-relative case (postcompose a chain with $f$ or precompose a cochain with $f$), but using relative (co)chains instead.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese so in this case, $X=E|_A$ and $Y=E$ if I understand correctly?

Comment: I realise I could have picked better letters instead of $A$ and $B$, but no, you have a continuous map $\pi : E \to B$ so $X = E$ and $Y = B$.